# Abort trap 6 when executing a compiled c program

Tags: c

I downloaded a command line program and I am fighting with the installation for hours now!

It is written in C, and the make proceeds without any error message! But when I then try to run the program, it is telling me "abort trap 6"

The makefile looks like this:

```
CC = gcc
CFLAGS =  -c -O -I$ -DCONS
LIBS = -lm

OBJS = method.o func.o  para.o \
    input.o nesto.o \
display_it.o impo.o


method2-2: $(OBJS)  
$(CC) $(OBJS) $(LIBS) -o method2-2
$(CC) -g $(OBJS) $(LIBS) -o method2-2_db

method.o: method.c
$(CC) $(CFLAGS) method.c
func.o: func.c 
$(CC) $(CFLAGS) func.c
input.o: input.c
$(CC) $(CFLAGS) input.c
nesto.o: nesto.c
$(CC) $(CFLAGS) nesto.c
para.o: para.c
```

Is it maybe wrong at some place?? I put a lot of println in the code to see where it breaks, and just before a method from input is called the error message occurs. 
Is this maybe a c problem  or should I contact the authors?

Comment: We can't say anything about the program's behaviour without seeing the code.

Comment: Do you have access to the source?  Could it be a `signal` perhaps?  A quick google search brought up several references to `free`ing pointers that haven't been allocated.

Comment: A C problem? Unlikely. Adopt Occam's razor approach. Blame (i) the way you're running the program, (ii) your build method, (iii) the program source code, (iv) the compiler in that order.

Comment: Ok, so I will check everything, but since I am not an expert I wanted to know if I totally miss something or I just have to check all of it :)

Comment: `OBJS` contains `display_it.o impo.o` but these files are not built. Do the targets `display_it.o : display_it.c` and `impo.o : impot.c` exist ? If not, what happen if you add them ?